# Render event inside if in forloop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar in angular and want to render my data in the calendar if they pass the if check.

The following are three slightly different examples of the same:

The forloop without the if sentence:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $scope.open_Courses.push({
           id: $scope.temp[i].id,
           title: $scope.temp[i].name,
           start: new Date($scope.temp[i].date).getTime(),
           editable: true,
           className: 'b-l b-2x b-info',
           location: $scope.temp[i].location,
           info: $scope.temp[i].description
        });
        //render event to calendar
        $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', $scope.open_Courses[i], true);
}
```

The loop with the if sentence but only render index 0 in array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        if (new Date($scope.temp[i].date).getTime() >= $scope.time) {
            $scope.open_Courses.push({
                id: $scope.temp[i].id,
                title: $scope.temp[i].name,
                start: new Date($scope.temp[i].date).getTime(),
                editable: true,
                className: 'b-l b-2x b-info',
                location: $scope.temp[i].location,
                info: $scope.temp[i].description
            });
            //render event to calendar
            $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', $scope.open_Courses[0], true);
        }
    }
```

And the last one with i-index in array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        if (new Date($scope.temp[i].date).getTime() >= $scope.time) {
            $scope.open_Courses.push({
                id: $scope.temp[i].id,
                title: $scope.temp[i].name,
                start: new Date($scope.temp[i].date).getTime(),
                editable: true,
                className: 'b-l b-2x b-info',
                location: $scope.temp[i].location,
                info: $scope.temp[i].description
            });
            //render event to calendar
            $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', $scope.open_Courses[i], true);
        }
    }
```

The first and second work fine but the last, which is how I want to do it, doesn't. It becomes undefined and errors out with:

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

For me the second and third example is basically identical so how can this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `i` in this case is incremented on each loop...regardless of the conditional. You're only pushing into `$scope.open_Courses` when the conditional passes. Therefore, `i` most likely will be at a higher index than `$scope.open_Courses`. For example, if your loop index (`i`) is at 5 and the length of `$scope.open_Courses` is 2, then `$scope.open_Courses[5]` would be undefined.

If you're wanting to render the last item, you will need to pass a valid index:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    if (new Date($scope.temp[i].date).getTime() >= $scope.time) {
        $scope.open_Courses.push({
            id: $scope.temp[i].id,
            title: $scope.temp[i].name,
            start: new Date($scope.temp[i].date).getTime(),
            editable: true,
            className: 'b-l b-2x b-info',
            location: $scope.temp[i].location,
            info: $scope.temp[i].description
        });
        //render event to calendar
        var len = $scope.open_Courses.length;
        $('.calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', $scope.open_Courses[len-1], true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course. As the data is now I don't expect to get anything out currently that is not passing the conditional. But I might overlook something there. This definitely does make sense!